# get content of web page include jquery using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: jquery, python, beautifulsoup

i try to parse an webpage using python and beautifulsoup.
I would like get the result when click on the "Submit" button.

```
<div class="orderButtonClass" onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{portfolioId:0}, url:'/cineday/commande/pinRequestWeb',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#line0').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){onFail();;}});">  

                    Submit

            </div>
```

Do you know how i can do that with python ?
With python i can parse the html but not the result of the POST in jquery.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Monitor the request that is being sent to the server on the click of the Submit button. You can use Developer tools (in Chrome), FireBug (in Firefox ) to monitor the request. Now, note down that URL and see the response for that request. You can use the Python requests library to mimic the GET/POST from the browser and then use BeautifulSoup ( if the response is HTML ) or JSON library to parse the output.